# Delay code in JAVA

Tags: java

I'd like to know if there is a way to delay code execution in java. If there is, kindly post a reply and please note that I'm not referring to java android here

Similar to system c where i can write something like:

```
delay_ms(1000);
```

to delay the code from execution for a minute

Answer (score 5):

**You can use:**

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

This causes the current Thread to sleep for 1000 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html

> Thread.sleep causes the current thread to suspend execution for a
>   specified period. This is an efficient means of making processor time
>   available to the other threads of an application or other applications
>   that might be running on a computer system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Thread.sleep(1000)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)) here.